# Command stops whenever I log out of my server

Tags: java, macos, bash, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I have a java program (text-based no GUI) that I have written and compiled and uploaded to a server.

I run it with `java -cp myjar.jar mypackage.MyClass` which starts it running processing a datafile with 20,000,000+ entries in it and printing output to `System.out`. I have calculated that it will take a very long time to process the data and I didn't want to have my laptop open for the 10 days of number crunching...

When I log out of my shell however, the process stops.

How can I execute the command and log out without it stopping? What is that even called?

I am using an Amazon Ubuntu EC2 server. I log in using a certificate from Mac OSX with terminal. The server seems to be using a bash shell.

Hope someone can help me out!
Jason.

Comment: On common Linux it could be done by `nohup java -cp myjar.jar mypackage.MyClass &`

Comment: Thanks! This works really well! I can't seem to up-vote your response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using **screen** instead of **nohup**. It allows you to create a virtual terminal that persists even after you logout/disconnect. When you reconnect to the server, you can immediately jump into the `screen` session you last had open.

Typical workflow on the server:

1. type `screen` (you may need to press space to leave intro page)
2. type in your command that you want to leave long-running (your java program, or an OS upgrade)
3. press `ctrl a+d` to leave screen (make sure to hold ctrl down)

To re-enter screen just use `screen -r`, and you will see the previous terminal and any running programs as you left it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nohup`

```
nohup java -cp myjar.jar mypackage.MyClass > yourLogFile.log &
```

`----->` http://ss64.com/bash/nohup.html

Comment: That was really fast! Thanks. What a neat way to do it. I can then read the output to see if it is done.